# Adding a new row to a table dynamically - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Currently I am populating a table as,

```
<%= form_tag({:action => :update}, :method => :put) do %>
  <table class="striped" id="player-table">
    <% @player_types.each_with_index do |p_type, i| %>
      <tr>
         <td><%= text_field_tag :name_player_type, p_type.name_player_type, :name => "p_types[#{i}][name_player_type]" %></td>
      </tr>
   <% end %>
  </table>
<% end %>
```

Now I want to add multiple new rows to this table of the same type(not using Ajax here) probably using javascript. The new row would be an empty field but I will obviously have to pass the data to the controller. Can anyone suggest a good way to go about it?

EDIT: I want to add a new row on the click of a button

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do? Also, code: `:name => p_types[#{i}][name_player_type]"` should be this: `:name => "p_types[#{i}][name_player_type]"` instead.

Comment: my bad, that was a typo there. Adding a new row to a populated table, the new row should have an empty text field tag.

Comment: whats the condition for adding new table row?

Comment: At the click of a button, sorry that is not clear there

Comment: why can't you add event listener to click, and function that adds new row to table? Sorry, i want to help, but its not very clear from my point of view. Do you need code examples or just what to do?

Comment: Code example would be great as I am new to rails. What to do would not be a bad start either

Comment: I see, checkout [this railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2) to understand how to add and remove fields on the form via jQuery.